# API data not being listed. What am I doing wrong in this code?

Tags: jquery, json, api

So I have this simple html test page to test out some code that uses jquery to fetch API in json format and then the jquery lists the data by updating the html, but the data does not list. API link works fine. Data should list hundreds of returned data. What am I missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/screen.css" type="text/css"     media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<link href="../css/highlight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("https://coinmap.org/api/v1/venues/",function(data){
    $.each(data.post, function(i,post){
        content += '<p>' + post.id + '</p>';
        content += '<p' + post.name+ '</p>';
        content += '<br/>';
        $(content).appendTo("#posts");
    });
});   
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="span-24">
                   <h2>Check out the following posts:</h2>
                    <div id="posts"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it that im using the API link directly in the getJason function? Do I need to get the data first via PHP or something and then feed the raw data file to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not accessing the data from the API correctly. Instead of `data.post` try `data.venues`.

```
$.each(data.venues, function(i,venue){
    content += '<p>' + venue.id + '</p>';
    content += '<p' + venue.name+ '</p>';
    content += '<br/>';
    $(content).appendTo("#posts");
});
```

Comment: That DID in fact work as now I see the data on the page loading. Not sure why it works just by changing the variable name but it did so thanks :-)

Comment: I now see that venues is listed in the JSON so we have ro precede access to the data through it. I get it now